# Codechef Total Expenses

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm using the following code to solve the problem at https://www.codechef.com/problems/FLOW009

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int T;
    float quantity, price, tex;
    scanf("%d", &T);

    while(T--)
    {
        scanf("%f %f", &quantity, &price);

        tex = quantity * price;
        if (quantity > 1000)
            tex = tex - (tex * 0.1);

        printf("%.6f\n", tex);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I don't know why this keeps giving me the wrong answer.

I tried changing the data type.

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int T, quantity, price;
    float tex;
    scanf("%d", &T);

    while(T--)
    {
        scanf("%d %d", &quantity, &price);

        tex = quantity * price;
        if (quantity > 1000)
            tex -= (tex * 0.1);

        printf("%.6f\n", tex);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But this gives the wrong answer too.

Comment: What "wrong" answers are you getting?

Comment: When I test it with the Sample Input, it gives the expected result but the online judge shows "Wrong Answer".

Comment: just as a side note:  regarding this expression: `(tex * 0.1);`  The `0.1` is a double literal.  You actually want a float literal,  I.E. `0.1f`

Comment: the posted code fails to cleanly compile.  always compile with all warnings enabled. (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` )  Then the compiler will tell you 1) unused parameter: `argc`  2) unused parameter: `argv[]`.    Those can be fixed by `int main( void )`  And I suspect submitting code that does not cleanly compile is a good way to get the answer rejected.

Comment: the problem description has these constraints:  
    1 ≤ T ≤ 1000
    1 ≤ quantity   price ≤ 100000  so the values need to be able to handle 100000*100000 which is 10 000 000 000 I.E. 10 gig, but an integer can only hold +/-2gig   So cannot use integer for total nor integer math for the multiplications.  Therefore, read the values as integers, but force the math to use `float` then display the resulting values as `%.6f` and if you decide to keep each result in an array, then that array needs to contain 1000 float entries.

Comment: I noticed, in the accepted answers that they are allowing `when quantity == 1000` to also get the discount!  Which seems to me, given the codechef statement of the problem, should not be accepted.

Comment: the codechef testing invokes a solution similar to:  `prog < testdata.txt`.  so no need to save all the output until the end of the program

Comment: this line: `tex -= (tex * 0.1);` has too much math.   Suggest: `tex *= 0.9f);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the question it is stated that all inputs including quantity and price are integers. You have declared them as float this can change some of your answers for input whose quantity is greater than 1000 like below:

```
1
1001 8
7207.200195 (your ans, correct = 7207.200000)
```

Due to floating point values. After modification code looks something like below

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int test, qty, price;
    double total;

    scanf("%d", &test);

    while(test--)
    {
        scanf("%d %d", &qty, &price);

        total = qty * price;

        if (qty > 1000)
            total -= ((total * 10.0)/100.0);

        printf("%.6lf\n", total);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried that. Changing the data type of quantity and price variables to type float doesn't work.

Comment: change them to integer and leave tex as float

Comment: Yeah, I left tex as float

Comment: you can run both the code on the sample input i have given it will show different output.

Comment: @danishansari please do not provide pat answers for online challenges. There are plenty of "crib" sites available.

Comment: @Weather Vane both the code in the question and the answer i gave are same, no logical difference.

Comment: Updated Question with the code which doesn't work too.

Comment: @WeatherVane it's not a challenge, but a practice problem.

Comment: @SnorkS it due to float, changing that to double will work, float has issues with floating point values.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to provide output after every input set. That is the reason your answer is getting rejected. Store the output in an array an print it at the end.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int T, quantity, price, i;
    double *tex = NULL;
    scanf("%d", &T);

    tex = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * T);

    for(i=0; i<T; i++)
    {                                 
        scanf("%d %d", &quantity, &price);

        tex[i] = (float)(quantity * price);
        if (quantity > 1000)        
            tex[i] -= (tex[i] * 0.1);

    }                     

    for(i=0; i<T; i++)
        printf("%.6lf\n", tex[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: changing to `double` will not fix the problem as 1) all the inputs are integers 2) `double` has the same kinds of `exact number representation` problems as does `float`

Comment: when calling `malloc()`,  1) in C, the returned value is a `void*` so can be assigned to any other pointer.  casting the returned value creates problems that are not necessary.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.   memory allocation errors can happen, even in the best of environments.

Comment: @user3629249 1.) If malloc isn't called, then we'd have to fix the size of memory to be allocated for tex, which seemed like memory wastage. 2.) Since the code was to be submitted to codechef, I didn't take into account memory allocation failure cases.

Comment: I never said to 'not use `malloc()`'.  I did say to perform error checking.  I did say to not cast the returned value from `malloc()`

Answer (score 0):

There's a function called *setprecision()* in the **iomanip** header file, which allows you to set the number of decimal places to which you would like to obtain your result. Printing the last bit would require you to write a statement like this-

```
cout<<fixed<<setprecision(6)<<total<<endl;
```

Comment: Sorry for that, I didn't notice it at first.